The operator norm regarding to the difference between a mollified function and the function itself
Let $\rho_\epsilon$ be a mollifier that has support in $B(0,\epsilon)$, define the operator
$$T_\epsilon (f)=\rho_\epsilon*f-f,$$
for every $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, can we prove or disprove that the operator norm
$$||T_\epsilon||=\sup_{||f||_{L^2}=1} ||T_\epsilon f||_{L^2}\rightarrow 0,$$
as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$? Is there a way to find the function that maximizes this operator norm?
We know that these operators are uniformly bounded (independent of $\epsilon$), by using Fourier transform:
$$||T_\epsilon||\leq ||\hat\rho-1||_{L^\infty}<\infty,$$
and we also know for each fixed $f\in L^2$, $||T_\epsilon f||_{L^2}\rightarrow 0$. However, I could not find any reference on the convergence speed in terms of $||f||_{L^2}$ and $\epsilon$.

You showed that in the frequency domain, $T_{\epsilon}$ is a multiplication operator on $L^2$ by $\hat{\rho_{\epsilon}} - 1$. It is well known that the norm of this multiplication operator is $\|M_{\hat{\rho_{\epsilon}} - 1}\| = \|\hat{\rho_{\epsilon}} - 1\|_{L^\infty}$. Assuming $\rho_{\epsilon}(x) = \epsilon^{-d}\rho(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ where $\int \rho(x)\,dx = 1$, we get $\hat{\rho_{\epsilon}}(\omega) = \hat{\rho}(\epsilon \omega)$. Hence $\|M_{\hat{\rho_{\epsilon}} - 1}\| = \|\hat{\rho}(\epsilon \omega) - 1\|_{L^{\infty}} = \|\hat{\rho} - 1\|_{L^{\infty}}$.
You can find the functions that saturate the norm. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. In the frequency domain, the functions $g_{\delta} = 1_{A_\delta}$, where $A_\delta$ is any finite measure subset of $\{\omega : |\hat{\rho}(\epsilon \omega) - 1| > \|\hat{\rho} - 1\|_{L^{\infty}} - \delta\}$ saturate the norm, that is, $\|(\hat{\rho}(\epsilon \omega) - 1)g_{\delta}\|_{L^2} \geq (\|\hat{\rho} - 1\|_{L^{\infty}} - \delta)\|g_{\delta}\|_{L^2}$.

It looks like $g_\delta(\omega)=0$ for $\delta<|| \hat \rho-1||_{L^\infty}$ since $\sup \hat \rho(\epsilon \omega)=1$.

Consider the example $\rho(x) = \frac{1}{2}I(-1 \leq x \leq 1)$. Then $$\hat{\rho}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x)e^{-2\pi i\omega x},dx = \text{sinc}(2\pi \omega).$$ Hence $|T_{\epsilon}| = |\hat{\rho} - 1|{L^{\infty}} \geq 1$. Note the functions $g{\delta}$ are only valid if the sets they represent have finite measure, but to get valid ones, take any subset of $g_{\delta}$ that has finite positive measure.

@Euler'slittlehelper I see, I was missing an absolute value in the definition of $g_{\delta}$. It's fixed now.

Thanks for your answer! If we restrict $f$ to a subset of $L^2$, say $C_c^\infty$, can the operator norm go to zero?

It depends on what subset and norm. $C_c^{\infty}$ with the $L^2$ norm is dense in $L^2$.
